# Powershell C# Cmdlet with Hashtable/Dictionary parameters

Tags: c#, powershell, parameters, hashtable, powershell-cmdlet

Can anyone tell me how to add a parameter to my custom C# cmdlets which is a Hashtable/StringDictionary, so that I can call my cmdlet in a way which resembles this:

```
 CustomCmdlet -File $someFilePath `
              -StringDictionary/HashtableParameter @{
                            "name1"="value1"
                            "name2"="value2"
                            "name3"="value3"
                            ...
                       }
```

I simply cannot find any documentation/example which clearly and simple explains how to do this, or if its even possible for custom cmdlets.

Can i just use:

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory = false, Position = 9)]
    public Dictionary<string,string> FieldValues { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = false, Position = 9)]
    public HashTable FieldValues { get; set; }

    ...
```

Or something else?

Kind regards

Comment: "Can i just use...?" - yes, it looks correct.

Comment: At least it definitely should work for `Hashtable`. Then you can pass values `@{...}` from your script to the cmdlet.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following

```
public Hashtable[] SearchCriteria { get; set; }
```

to have the funcitonality like

```
Start-Process calc -PassThru | Get-UIAWindow | Get-UIAButton -SearchCriteria @{automationid="13*";name="[3-5]"},@{name="c*"},@{name="a*"},@{isenabled="false"} | Read-UIAControlName
```

The output is

4

Clear entry

5

Clear

3

Add

Maximize

Close

Comment: The `Hashtable` class is in the `System.Collections` namespace in case anyone else is looking.